# v-model complains about props and data

Tags: vue.js

Tinkering with Vue for the first time, I have a rather innocuous input like so:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" v-model="quantity" />
```

This lives inside a component.

When quantity is set on the `prop` object, I get this error (when changing the value in the input):

```
Vue.component('my-product', {props: {quantity : {default: 1}}});
```

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "quantity"`

But when quantity is set on the `data` object as demonstrated on the [Vue tutorial documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage), I get this error:

```
Vue.component('my-product', {data: {quantity : 1}});
```

`[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.`

I'm at a loss. This field has no bearing on the parent views (vues?) so perhaps I am simply misunderstanding how to set this up.

Comment: data in the vue instance is an js object, but in a vue component must be a function, change `{data: {quantity : 1}}` to `{data(){ return {quantity : 1}}}`

Comment: @birdspider haha just figured that out... should have just kept reading docs

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's right there in the error text...

```
Vue.component('my-product', {
  data: function(){ 
      return {quantity : 1}
  }
});
```

Comment: Just to add on to this, there may be many components using the same data property.  By making it a function, it can return a new object each time it is called, so you don't end up with components sharing the same data object.

[Reference](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data)